# How to successfully clean your house with a bird, wood, and wool

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I only want to clean my house in a way that is 100% Torah-approved. The way that is mentioned in the Torah is to use cedar, wool, hyssop, and a live bird. However, I am a bit confused.

How, exactly, am I supposed to use these elements to clean my house? The pasuk only states, "And he shall cleanse the house with the blood of the bird, the spring water, the live bird, the cedar wood, the hyssop, and the strip of crimson wool" ("וְחִטֵּ֣א אֶת־הַבַּ֔יִת בְּדַם֙ הַצִּפּ֔וֹר וּבַמַּ֖יִם הַֽחַיִּ֑ים וּבַצִּפֹּ֣ר הַֽחַיָּ֗ה וּבְעֵ֥ץ הָאֶ֛רֶז וּבָֽאֵזֹ֖ב וּבִשְׁנִ֥י הַתּוֹלָֽעַת:). It doesn't say in what way or in what order to do it. For example, would I use the bird to clean my mirrors and then the hyssop to mop my floors? Or vice versa? Assuming I have done the other steps (dipping the bird into the blood, sending the bird to fly away, and sprinkling the blood toward my house), how do I finish the job of getting my house Torah-clean?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verse that you cited actually speaks of two birds - one dead, one alive.

My grandma, Bubby Sally, a wonderful Sefardic woman used this method to clean her house before Shabbat. She lived on a farm so she had access to chickens, readily. Here's what she did:

One chicken had to be slaughtered so the family could have chicken on Shabbat. As the house was always clean during the week, she had to dirty it up somehow so that she could do the mitzvah of cleaning it for Shabbat. So, she spilled the blood of the slaughtered chicken on the floor.

The cedar wood was a standard in the house as she had a cedar closet to keep things smelling fresh.

The hyssop was a main ingredient of *za'atar*, which she used to flavor her Shabbat chicken. (I highly recommend this, BTW. You get moist tasty chicken!)

So, now there is blood on the floor. Next, the hyssop was sprinkled on the Shabbat chicken, and that was cooked. Then, she got a live chicken from her farm, and used its feathers to mop the floor clean and dust the house. Yes the live chicken was a bloody mess, but it went outside in the rain later, anyway.

Oh, you mentioned spring water, too. That was poured on the floor to get it cleaner.

Finally, the crimson wool. Well, she had a beautiful special fluffy crimson woolen towel that had been kept in the cedar closet. That was a special Shabbat towel that she used to dry the floor.

So, there you have it. If you ever use this method to clean your house for Shabbat, you can thank my Bubby Sally.

Shabbat Shalom.

Comment: Glad to hear that's how your Bubby did it. This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.

Comment: @SAH I have to admit. My Bubby Sally passed her weirdness genes on to me :-%